# What is the best place to read/write/store a small amount of data online?

Tags: java, csv, storage

I want to be able to store, retrieve, and modify a small amount of textual data (< 2 mb) as a CSV online. What service should I use to be able to do this programatically (in Java)?

Comment: what kind of data? text? structured records? binary?

Comment: Doesn't really matter on the format given the wide variety of serialisers around (json, protobuff, amf, xml, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google Spreadsheets ([Java API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)). You can [upload a CSV](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#UploadingSpreadsheet) which gets automatically converted to a spreadsheet, then you can [query](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#SendingStructuredQueries) or edit it programmatically, or [manipulate it online](http://docs.google.com/), then if you need to get it as CSV you can [export it](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets).

Answer (score 1):

You can try Google's App Engine.  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html

Also there is Amazon S3.  http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

I know a few Open Source people using these tools to store online persistent data to useful effect.

Comment: As far as I am aware the Datastore on App Engine has a free quota mode.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenDHT sounds like it will do what you need it to.

http://www.opendht.org/